# Display tagged list as indented tree grid

Tags: list, tree, treeview

I am writing a logger which records the level of the entries.
To make it simple, let's say it logs entries like `<level> <message>`.
I am now trying to write a log viewer which formats the logfile "nicely" as an indented tree grid.
For example is the raw log file contains:

```
0 entry1
0 entry2
1 entry3
2 entry4
3 entry5
2 entry6
0 entry7
```

It should output:

```
entry1
entry2
└entry3
 ├entry4
 │└entry5
 └entry6
entry7
```

My first steps were

1. Converting the list into a tree
2. Recursively print the tree

This worked with one single exception: I cannot figure out how I can pass the information that - referring to the example - before `entry5` comes the `│` sign to display that the previous level continues after the sub-levels.
So any hint, how to come from the list to the desired output is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it:

```
class LogViewer(LogFile):
    """
    Formats raw log file contents nicely 
    and thus makes it human-readable
    """
    __down = False

    class EntryTreeNode():
        """
        A minimal entry wrapper
        """
        def __init__(self, string):
            """
            Constructor
            """
            lst = string.split(LogEntry.colsep())
            if len(lst) != 6:
                raise Exception('Invalid entry: ' + string)
            else:
                self.DATE = datetime.strptime(lst[0], LogEntry.timeformat())
                self.ERRLVL = ErrLvlType(lst[1])
                self.USER = lst[2]
                self.CALLER = lst[3]
                self.OFFSET = int(lst[4])
                self.MSG = lst[5]

                self.tag = self.OFFSET
                self.children = []
                self.pre = '[' + datetime.strftime(self.DATE, LogEntry.timeformat()) + ']\t' \
                    + str(self.ERRLVL) + '\t' \
                    + str(self.USER) + '\t'
                self.post = str(self.CALLER) + '       \t' + str(self.MSG)

        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self.tag)


    def __init__(self, path):
        """
        Constructor
        """
        super().__init__(path)

    @property
    def __sym_last(self):
        """
        Returns the symbol for a last entry
        """
        return '┌' if self.__down else '└'

    @property
    def __sym_mid(self):
        """
        Returns the symbol for a middle entry
        """
        return '├'

    @property
    def __sym_follow(self):
        """
        Returns the symbol for a following entry
        """
        return '│'

    def __mktree(self, lst):
        """
        Converts a log entry list into a tree
        """
        roots = []

        def children(root, lst):
            result = []
            while lst:
                curr = lst.pop()
                if curr.tag == root.tag + 1:
                    curr.children = children(curr, lst)
                    result.append(curr)
                else:
                    lst.append(curr)
                    break
            return result

        while lst:
            curr = lst.pop()
            if curr.tag == 0:
                curr.children = children(curr, lst)
                roots.append(curr)
        return roots


    def __print_tree(self, root, offset='', prefix='', last=True):
        """
        Prints a log entry tree
        """
        print(root.pre + offset + prefix + root.post)
        if last:
            offset += ' '
        else:
            offset += self.__sym_follow
        for i in range(0, len(root.children)):
            if i == len(root.children)-1:
                prefix = self.__sym_last
                last = True
            else:
                prefix = self.__sym_mid
                last = False
            self.__print_tree(root.children[i], offset, prefix, last)

    def display(self, reverse=False):
        """
        Displays the log file nicely
        """
        self.__down = reverse
        entries = reversed(self.dump()) if reverse else self.dump()
        entries = [self.EntryTreeNode(e) for e in entries]

        tree = self.__mktree(entries)
        for root in tree:
            self.__print_tree(root)
```